# Is it possible to sign a transaction programmatically via a connected cold storage wallet?

Tags: security, coldstorage

Lets say I want to generate my own transactions and sign them myself via my computer. Signing them in the computer would require me to input my private key, which would compromise the key. Is it possible to connect the cold storage wallet to the computer and sign them on the cold storage wallet without compromising the keys?

I ask because I recently read about google chrome indexing all of the files on your computer into their google cloud (possibly only windows, but wouldn't be surprised if mac too and/or microsoft/apple doing the same thing)

Answer (score 2):

> it possible to connect the cold storage wallet to the computer

Then it's not cold storage anymore. By definition, keys in cold storage are not connected to anything, and require physical access to communicate with.

> and sign them on the cold storage wallet without compromising the keys?

Sure, but that's just called a hardware wallet. There are several vendors that create them.

Comment: If a wallet is accessible only on localhost and none of the machines on local network are connected to internet. Is it cold storage?

Comment: Yes, that's primarily what I'd imagine cold storage to be: an offline machine with keys that never leave the device.

Comment: Though I'd not conmect the machine to any kind of network, just because it means less things to secure.

Comment: Yes it makes sense.